# Best one/single page website/module or theme for drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I wonder if anyone can recommend an easy to use module or theme to create a single page drupal website. Something like this: http://rhythm.nikadevs.com/node/7/8

All suggestions are welcome.

I have already heard about single page module, singe webpage module, and various themes on (e.g.) themeforest but they all seem very different. Which one should a novice use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First of all, http://rhythm.nikadevs.com/node/7/8 is not a exactly a single page website. If you like the design, then here is the page with a theme that they're using [Rhythm - Multipurpose Commerce Drupal theme](http://themeforest.net/item/rhythm-multipurpose-commerce-drupal-theme/10876314)

If you want to make something like [this](http://www.starfisk.com/) then there is a [Single Page Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) module for that kind of pages. Fairly easy to use and most likely you will have a good time with it.

As a Drupal developer myself, I would not recommend Drupal as a platform for a single page websites. From my experience, using it for this kind of application is an unnecessary over-complication, unless you have a very strong reason.

Comment: I have actually bought that theme that you are linking me to, but it utilizes a Visual Shortcodes system to build up the layout, and that system is very unintuitive and frankly difficult to handle. Thats why i posted this question, to find any good suggestions, which I am thankful that you provide! =)